# getting sourceViewController of modal segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Can I get `sourceViewController` of modal segue after `preareForSegue:`?

```
[UINavigationController]
  |-[ViewControllerA]-------\
                             |--(modal)--> [UINavigationController]-[ViewControllerC]
[UINavigationController]     |
  |-[ViewControllerB]-------/
```

After finishing `ViewControllerC`, I want to perform unwind segue of `sourceViewController`.

I wrote the following code but it doesn't work

```
    if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class]]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindToViewControllerA" sender:self];
    } else if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerB class]]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindToViewControllerB" sender:self];
    }
```

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Try `self.navigationController.presentingViewController` in place of `self.presentingViewController`.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very helpful. What result does your code give? Have you tried logging self.presentingViewController?

Comment: `self.presentingViewController` is SWRevealViewController and `self.navigationController.presentingViewController` is nil

Comment: Is ViewController-C an instance of NavigationController, or the rootViewController of the NavigationController?